# Intersecting a non-principal filter on $\Bbb Z$ with $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

Does there exist a non-principal filter $\mathscr F$ on $\Bbb Z$ such that $\mathscr F \cap \mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ is principal?

Answer (score 3):

I’ll get you started.

Suppose that $\mathscr{F}$ is a filter on $\Bbb Z$ such that $\mathscr{F}\cap\wp(\Bbb N)$ is a principal filter on $\Bbb N$. Let $\mathscr{G}=\mathscr{F}\cap\wp(\Bbb N)$; then there is some non-empty $A\subseteq\Bbb N$ such that $\mathscr{G}=\{G\subseteq\Bbb N:A\subseteq F\}$. In particular, $A\in\mathscr{G}\subseteq\mathscr{F}$.

Let $F\in\mathscr{F}$ be arbitrary; then $\varnothing\ne F\cap A\in\mathscr{F}$. But $F\cap A\subseteq\Bbb N$, so $F\cap A\in\mathscr{F}\cap\wp(\Bbb N)=\mathscr{G}$, and therefore $A\subseteq F\cap A$, i.e., $F\cap A=A$. In other words, $F\supseteq A$ for each $F\in\mathscr{F}$. What can you now conclude about $\mathscr{F}$?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the rationale behind using the Weierstrass $\wp$ for power set?

Comment: @Lord_Farin: In handwriting I’ve always distinguished the power set P from all other uses of the letter, and $\wp$ is very close to the form that I do use for power set. $\mathscr{P}$ is a reasonable approximation to my script P, and $\mathcal{P}$ is an abomination. (I’m a little picky about these things: I’m out of practice, but I used to [do a fair bit of calligraphy](http://cleftlands.cwru.edu/archive/picture.asp?id=61).)

Comment: Thanks for your reply; nice calligraphy! I usually keep my letters straightforward since I'm not so gifted with the pencil. It already took some decent effort to have a consistent signature, and it took a few pages to find a nice way of writing an $\aleph$.